# Conditional row display in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

Suppose there is sample code in jsp as follows :

I want that when i enter the data in text field and click on "Add Item" button, the whole row should be replicated below the current row. In addition to this the previous row should have retain its data and the new row should be empty. Need your help.

Comment: Are you asking how to do it all client-side, with JavaScript? (If so, you probably want your button to be `type="button"`.) What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of thing I would do purely client side, and use jQuery:

```
<table id = "myTable">
<tr id="myRow">
 <td>Quantity</td>
 <td><input type="text" size="10" style="background-color: aqua" name="quantity"> </td>
 <td>Price</td>
 <td><input type="text" disabled="disabled" size="10" style="background-color: aqua" name="price"></td>
 <td><input type="button" id="copyRow" value="Add Item" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and some jQuery:

```
$('#copyRow).clone("#myRow").appendTo('#myTable');
```